Standard electrode potential from thermodynamic data
I am looking for a reference where the values of standard electrode potentials of simple reactions calculated from the heat of submilation, energy of ionization, energy of hydration and possibly other thermodynamic data are compared to their electrochemical values.
Ideally a table containing each enthalpic contribution $\Delta H_i$, $\Delta S$, $\Delta G$, $E_0$ and $E^{exp}_0$.

You cannot limit it to just thermodynamic data, as kinetics is involved as well.

kinetics is not involved in Hess's Law calculations. Much data is in the various handbooks such as Langes, NIST tables, Wikipedia etc. Research requires effort, but worry not, in a few years artificial intelligence will search all available data and compile it into one simple data base and answer all questions. Please pardon the sarcasm. A good place to start: https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Oxidation_States_of_the_Elements_and.html?id=Q68LAQAAIAAJ Latimer's book on oxidation states and potentials. I recommend Lange's handbook followed by the chemistry library in a university.

The New York City public library on 5th Ave and Columbia Univ libraries are great. Have lunch with the lions: https://www.nypl.org/locations/schwarzman

@jimchmst I had a look on Latimer, it has a good introduction to such calculations, it also has extensive data for the needed energies. But it does not have table explicitly comparing the thermodynamic estimates with the electrochemical values. If I overlooked please indicate the page.

@jimchmst To be more precise about what I am asking : I once read in a book the explicit use of sublimation energy, ionization energy and hydration energy to derive standard potential of Zinc/Copper redox reaction and it was $ 1.1 V$ exactly matching the well-known eletrochemical value. Unfortunately the book made this comparison only for that reaction (and I actually forgot which book it was).

Having a table listing the thermodynamic and the electrochemical values with each part of the thermodynamic value written in the table would give some intuition on which part contributes mostly in which cases.

Sometimes if one wants some data they must work it out themselves. Research! The way I understand it is that many half-cell voltages, especially for composite reactions, have been determined from thermal data. I would be curious about potentials that have fewer significant figures
